# Concatenate connection string

Tags: bash

This connection string works for psql:

```
psql "password='${INPUT_PASSWORD}' dbname=analytics host='${INPUT_HOST}' user=analytics port=32648"
```

I want to make it more readable, tried:

```
psql "password='${INPUT_PASSWORD}'" +
     "dbname=analytics" +
     "host='${INPUT_HOST}'" +
     "user=analytics" +
     "port=32648"
```

Gives `"error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory"`

Then tried:

```
psql "password='${INPUT_PASSWORD}'" \
     "dbname=analytics" \
     "host='${INPUT_HOST}'" \
     "user=analytics" \
     "port=32648"
```

Which gives the same error.

Is there a way that I can split the string onto multiple lines and still have it accepted as a connection string by Postgres?

Comment: In the first version, you pass a total of 9 arguments to psql (each `+` being a single argument). In the second version, you are passing 5 arguments. The original, single-line approach, passes one argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just:

```
psql "password='${INPUT_PASSWORD}'
      dbname=analytics
      host='${INPUT_HOST}'
      user=analytics
      port=32648"
```

(as answer, because you cannot do multi-line in the comments)

Comment: Ah! That does indeed work, thank you. (Deleting this comment shortly)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your second attempt is that you inject unquoted whitespace between each argument and its following backslash. Since the spaces are intended to be *in* the argument, they need to be quoted as well.

```
psql "password='${INPUT_PASSWORD}' "\
     "dbname=analytics "\
     "host='${INPUT_HOST}' "\
     "user=analytics "\
     "port=32648"
```

Using `bash`, I would define an array instead, and let array parameter expansion insert the spaces.

```
psql_args=(
    "password='$INPUT_PASSWORD'"
    dbname=analytics
    "host='${INPUT_HOST}'"
    user=analytics
    port=32648
)

psql "${psql_args[*]}"
```

(Actually, since you appear to be constructing the conninfo string yourself, rather than receiving it via some other configuration file, I would probably use the options to specify each piece of information instead.)